# Is there an equivalent of the following in prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, equivalent

Particularly the bit about live....

```
 jQuery('.something').live('click', function() {
     jQuery(this).parent('form').reset();
 });
```

I suppose this might work as well, though I am curious about the parent function:

```
 jQuery('.something').live('click', function() {
     this.form.reset();
 });
```

Comment: Exact to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479782/prototype-equivalent-for-jquery-live-function

Comment: It is, if we don't care about the parent() part, I do.

Comment: I missed the "parent" part of your question; answer updated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Live

Prototype doesn't currently have "live" support. You can do something similar with event delegation, though. That's where you watch for the event on a parent element, and then in the event handler find out which child element the event actually happened on:

```
$('theFormID').observe('click', handleFormClick);
function handleFormClick(event) {
    var element;

    // Get the element on which the click occurred
    element = event.findElement();
}
```

Event delegation is only possible with events that bubble (like 'click'); I don't know if jQuery's live stuff has that same issue.

One nice thing is that you can pass CSS selectors into [`Event#findElement`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/event.html#findelement-class_method):

```
$('tbodyID').observe('click', handleTableClick);
function handleTableClick(event) {
    var element;

    // Get the element on which the click occurred
    element = event.findElement('tr');
}
```

...which finds the `tr` that was clicked, even if the actual click occurred within a `span` inside a `td` inside the `tr`.

Proper use of event delegation can dramatically simplify hooking/unhooking elements, particular when you're adding and removing elements dynamically.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a plug-in for Prototype that does "live" support.

#### Parent

You mentioned that you want to get the parent of the clicked control. When you hook up a handler with Prototype, by default it sets things up so that within your handler, `this` references the element on which you've set the event handler. So for instance, if you have a `div` with the id `foo`:

```
$('foo').observe('click', function(event) {
    // Here, `this` will refer to the `foo` element
});
```

You can then use Prototype's [Element#up](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#up-class_method) to get the parent element. (If you're using event delegation and you hook the event *on the parent* in the first place, of course just use `this` directly and if you also need to get a reference to the thing that was clicked, use `#findElement` as above.)

Comment: TJ, I believe there's some discussion in adding a .live implementation in Prototype. Would it be saved for a major release?

Comment: @Thrope: I think there is a plan to do it, yes. I don't know which release they're targeting it for, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were 1.7. You could ask here, it will get in front of the right eyes: http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous