# Can't access Elements previously created by innerHTML with Javascript/Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am setting the innerHTML variable of a div with contents from an ajax request:

```
new Ajax.Request('/search/ajax/allakas/?ext_id='+extid,
  {
    method:'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport){
      var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
      $('admincovers_content').innerHTML=response;
    },
    onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
  });
```

The response text cotains a form:

```
    <form id="akas-admin" method="post" action="/search/ajax/modifyakas/">
        <input type="text" name="formfield" value="i am a form field"/>
    </form>
```

Then I call a functiont that should submit that form:

```
$('akas-admin').request({
  onComplete: function(transport){ 
      //alert('Form data saved! '+transport.responseText)
        $('admincovers_content').innerHTML=transport.responseText;
      }
});
```

The problem is `$('akas-admin)` returns `null` , I tried to put the form with this id in the original document, which works.

Question: Can I somehow "revalidate" the dom or access elements that have been inserted with innerHTML?

Edit Info: `document.getElementById("akas-admin").submit()` works just fine, problem is i don't want to reload the whole page but post the form over ajax and get the response text in a callback function.

Edit:

Based on the answers provided, i replaced my function that does the request with the following observer:

```
Event.observe(document.body, 'click', function(event) {
  var e = Event.element(event);
  if ('aka-savelink' == e.identify()) {
      alert('savelink clicked!');
      if (el = e.findElement('#akas-admin')) {
        alert('found form to submit it has id: '+el.identify());
        el.request({
            onComplete: function(transport){ 
            alert('Form data saved! '+transport.responseText)
                $('admincovers_content').innerHTML=transport.responseText;
            }
        });
      }
  }
});
```

problem is that i get as far as `alert('savelink clicked!')`; . findelement doesnt return the form. i tried to place the save link above and under the form. both doesnt work.
i also think this approach is a bit clumsy and i am doing it wrong. could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("akas-admin").submit()`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - that works fine! but id like to submit usint ajax and get the response text in a callback. seems to be a prototype problem.

Comment: @Joe you said you wanted to submit the form, so can't see any reason why not doing it with pure JavaScript.. unless you want something else?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard i don't want to leave/reload the current page but have the response text of the sumbmission request in javascript.

Comment: @Joe oh sorry, thought you meant "real" submission. Not familiar with `prototype.js` but as last resort you can switch to jQuery, where I do know that such things work.

Comment: When do you call that function that submits your form? Make sure it's called right after Ajax request completed. Also adding a setTimeout might help

Comment: it should be called when a user clicks a link to submit it. i think about creating the form in javascript and just passing the data using json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `$('akas-admin')` returns `null` but `document.getElementById("akas-admin")` does not. The `$` function is mostly just a wrapper for `document.getElementById` so it's unusual for this to break down. Have you tried using `Element.extend(document.getElementById('akas-admin'))`?

Do you have any other libraries loaded? Can you recreate the problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: this looks very, very promising! gonna try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/); since your form is added after the DOM has loaded. Try this:

> $("#akas-admin").live('request',function(){
>   //Do your stuff here    })

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks promising! but this is jquery. is there anything similar in prototype?

Comment: this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479782/prototype-equivalent-for-jquery-live-function

Comment: thanks! i tried to do it but cant get it working. i posted my code into the answer, could you have a look at it?

Answer (score -1):

When you hear hoof beats, think horses not zebras.  Do you actually have an element with the id 'admincovers_content'?

Comment: OP says `$('akas-admin')` returns null, which breaks the script before even trying to retrieve 'admincovers_content'.