# Click Event Not Working After Ajax Content Added

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

Basically, I have a page which on page loading fetches Ajax content. The lightbox (which is unrelated to the ajax content) has `Event.observe` click events that stop working when the ajax products are loaded. I can get this to work with jQuery's `.live` method but am not familiar with Prototype.

SAMPLE NOT WORKING CLICK EVENT:

```
Event.observe('closeLink', 'click', function () {  
    RunSomeFuntion.close();          
    ClearAll();  
});
```

How do I get the events (see above) to remain functional using Prototype, even if Ajax content is added on page load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototype equivalent for jQuery live function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479782/prototype-equivalent-for-jquery-live-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation is the solution. Use `on`. See http://prototypejs.org/learn/event-delegation.

```
$('ancestorID').on('click', '.closeLink', function(event, element) {
    var clickedLink = event.element;
    RunSomeFuntion.close();
    ClearAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to re-execute your event bindings. Prototype doesn't not have anything similar to `.live`, unfortunately.